# Console log in useEffect prints nothing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, use-effect

I can't seem to figure out why this piece of React code isn't console logging any of the values...

```
  const [href, setHref] = useState("");
  const [whatever, setWhatever] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    setHref(window.location.href);
    setWhatever(href + " cats");

    console.log(whatever);
    console.log(href);
  }, []);
```

Comment: Why do you need to put the location into state?

Comment: it is asynchronous, you wont see the result immediately. please read how react works.

Comment: You should also be seeing a linting error. _"React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'href' and 'whatever'. Either include them or remove the dependency array."_

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately

Answer (score 0):

It prints nothing because you can not access new state immediately after you update state - state is accessed from closure and closure is recreated only after element rerenders. Since your effect is executing only once there is no way you can log new state within effect, move console log out of the effect and you will log fresh values after each rerender.